# Laravel Migration in PHP Project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

**TL;DR**

is there a way to use **Laravel - Database migration** in a PHP Project without using Laravel???

**Long version**

Laravel Provides Database migrations which work very well when you want to maintain the history of Database Changes and it takes out the hassle of Database migration and makes it simple to set up the database and get started with application development.

I am working on a very simple PHP application with minimal requirements which does not require a framework like **Laravel** or **Lumen**.

I got the necessary components like **Request**, **Response**, and **Blade Templating** but database migration is still a challenge and I am willing to use Database Migrations of Laravel.

So I was just thinking, is there a way to use **Laravel - Database migration** in a PHP Project without using Laravel.

Comment: You can set it up in different project/sub folder and use the same database and do migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a quick search on google it is possible to use Eloquent separate from Laravel. As database migrations are part of Eloquent this will fit your request as well.
Sources can be found [here](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/use-eloquent-without-laravel-7e1c73d79977) and [here](https://siipo.la/blog/how-to-use-eloquent-orm-migrations-outside-laravel)

Comment: In your second link, it's clearly mentioned that Laravel migrations cannot be used in outside Laravel project, they are using another independent migrations package in their example. 
In the first link it's also not clear how to use the migrations. The example only shows to create table, but that doesn't manage migrations (like it will try to create the same table again if I run the same file again).